# Conditional Probability Summation Rule Problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

From Blitzstein, *Introduction to Probability* (2019 2 edn), Chapter 2, Exercise 25, p 87.

> 25. A crime is committed by one of two suspects, A and B. Initially, there is equal
>     evidence against both of them. In further investigation at the crime scene, it is
>     found that the guilty party had a blood type found in 10% of the population.
>     Suspect A does match this blood type, whereas the blood type of Suspect B is
>     unknown.
>
> (a) Given this new information, what is the probability that A is the guilty
> party?

So here is my approach. Let $A$ stands for "A gulity", $M$ for "A matching the blood type" and $N$ for "B matching the blood type". Then
$$P(A|M) = P(A|M,N)P(N|M) + P(A|M,N^{C})P(N^{C}|M)$$
$$P(A|M) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{10} + 1\frac{9}{10} = \frac{19}{20}$$
Here it is inferred that the blood type of B is independant of that of A and that if both have the matching blood type they are equally likely to be guilty.

Where is the flaw in the application of the summation rule above? The correct answer is $\frac{10}{11}$.

Comment: I think you are right. I come up with $19/20$ myself.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I've read the solution and it is sount too and given that it is published by a Harvard Proffesor of Statistics I assume I'm wrong :D

Comment: You always have to consider party B since the negation of "A gulity" is "B guilty".

Comment: How does the author arrive at his result? I am afraid the reasoning is similar to the "one of my two kids is a boy"-problem

Comment: The problem is: The fact that blood type $X$ is found at the crime scene modifies the probabilities that the suspects have that blood type (even before testing $A$, we know that at least one of them has it while me might have expected this only with about 20% chance)

Comment: This is already known as game theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the blood type found at crime seen be X.

Probability that A is gulity **prior** to the new evidence $P(A)=1-P(B)=0.5$

Probability that blood type of X is found **given** A is gulty $=$ Probability that A has the blood type $P(X|A)=1$

Probability that blood type of X is found **given** B is guilty $=$ Probability that B has the blood type $P(X|B)=0.1$

Now it is known that blood type is X, and given exactly one of A or B is guilty,

$$P(A|X) = \frac{P(X|A)P(A)}{P(X)} = \frac{P(X|A)P(A)}{P(X|A)P(A)+P(X|B)P(B)} = \frac{10}{11}$$

Comment: Isn't P(X) = 1 always?

Comment: @Gerry See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4215193.

Answer (score 3):

I made the same mistake! I think the flaw is in the assumption that B's probability of having blood type X is 10%. B is already under suspicion for the crime; before we discovered that the perp has blood type X, there was a 50% chance that B was guilty. Hence B's chances of having blood type X are **higher** than 10%, since, as I understand it, B's likelihood of having the guilty blood type isn't independent of his being under suspicion.

By Bayes' Rule, B's probability of having blood type X = $\frac{\frac{1}{10}}{\frac{1}{10}+\frac{9}{10}*\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{2}{11}$. Plugging that into your equation, we have A's probability of guilt = $\frac{2}{11}*\frac{1}{2} + \frac{9}{11} = \frac{10}{11}$. So your logic itself was fine, but it involved a flawed estimate of B's chances of having the guilty blood type.

Comment: I quote the last sentence in your first para. *"since, as I understand it, B's likelihood of having the guilty blood type isn't independent of his being under suspicion."* **Why? Why isn't B's likelihood of having the guilty party's blood type, independent of B's being under suspicion?**

Answer (score 1):

Using Bayes' theorem:
$$
   \Pr(A\mid M) = \frac{\Pr(M|A) \Pr(A)}{\Pr(M\mid A) \Pr(A) + \Pr(M \mid B) \Pr(B)}
$$
and $\Pr(A) = \Pr(B) = \tfrac{1}{2}$ since both have equal evidence against them, $\Pr(M\mid A) = 1$ since match is certain if $A$ is indeed guilty, and $\Pr(M \mid B) = \Pr(M) = \tfrac{1}{10}$ since the match of $A$ is not dependent on the guilt of $B$,  you get $\Pr(A \mid M) = \tfrac{10}{11}$.

Comment: I get that, it's same as author solution, but I was wondering where is the mistake in the one with the summation rule cause I fail to see it and that drives me crazy. I'm starting to think that probably $P(N|M) \neq 0.1$ and having the blood type found at the crime seen, is that correct?

Comment: I am not too sure whether $P(A|M,N) = 0.5$, or what it even means