# Why is the probability of an event we know happened in a specific problem not equal to 1?

Tags: probability

From Blitzstein, *Introduction to Probability* (2019 2 edn), Chapter 2, Exercise 25, p 87.

> A crime is committed by one of two suspects, A and B. Initially, there
> is equal evidence against both of them. In further investigation at
> the crime scene, it is found that the guilty party had a blood type
> found in 10% of the population. Suspect A does match this blood type,
> whereas the blood type of Suspect B is unknown. Given this new information, what is the probability that A is the guilty party?

Let event A be "Person A committed the crime" and let event M be "Person A's blood type matches that of guilty party." We want to find $P(A|M)$.
$$P(A|M) = \frac{P(M|A)P(A)}{P(M)} = \frac{P(M|A)P(A)}{P(M|A)P(A) + P(M|A^c)P(A^c)} = \frac{1 \cdot \frac{1}{2}}{(1\cdot \frac{1}{2}) + (\frac{1}{10}\cdot \frac{1}{2})} = \frac{10}{11}$$

Here is my question: why is $P(M) \neq 1$? The problem says $M$ **happened**. I know we must use LOTP to calculate $M$ like how I did above, but I'm not totally sure why. My intuition is telling me that $M$ is an abstract event that didn't necessarily *happen*; it only happened in *this* problem. For instance, if we view $P$ as a probability function, it doesn't *know* that $M$ happened. Is this right thinking?

Thank you!

Comment: It's a bit hard to sort out what is being assumed here.  Let's say we assume that, a priori, the chance that both $A,B$ have the characteristic is $.01$ while the chance that $A$ does and $B$ doesn't is $.09$.  These are the only states in which $A$ has the characteristic.  Thus, given that $A$ does have it, the probability that $B$ also has it is $.1$ as you would expect.  Since $A$ is certain to be guilty if $B$ lacks the characteristic, and $A$ has a $.5$ chance of being guilty if $B$ also has it, then the conditional probability that $A$ is guilty is $.9\times 1 +.1\times .5 = .95$.

Comment: Should add: this sort of "reasoning" has actually been used in court cases, and it is usually a terrible idea.  To argue along these lines we must be magically certain that one of the two is guilty with equal odds (all else being equal) and we must be sure that the presence of the characteristic was independent of whatever made them suspects in the first place.

Comment: The implicit assumptions are that $P[M|A]=1$ and $P[M|A^c]=1/10$, under which the solution $10/11$ is correct (these assumptions do not fit Lulu's example). The problem says "given this new information" which is language that shows it wants you to use conditional probability to compute $P[A|M]$ in terms of the given info for $P[A], P[M|A], P[M|A^c]$. So indeed the $P$ doesn't "know" that $M$ happened. Minimally you can partition the sample space according to the 4 disjoint events $A\cap M$, $A \cap M^c$, $A^c \cap M$, $A^c \cap M^c$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional Probability Summation Rule Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634865/conditional-probability-summation-rule-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is my question: why is $P(M)≠1$? The problem says $M$ happened.

$\mathsf P(M)$ is *not* measured under the condition that $M$ happens.   It is the unconditioned probability that $M$ happens.

View it as: how probable we should think it was *prior* to learning that it was fact.

---

When we measure probability under a condition, we always indicate that condition.   $\mathsf P(A\mid M)$ is the probability for $A$ under condition of $M$.    AKA the conditional probability for $A$ when given $M$.

When we don't indicate such a condition, the measure does not assume that the condition occurred.

Comment: Yes! That was my thinking, but wanted to clarify. Thank you!

Comment: You posted a similar answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1935597.